# How to have a colored border around a webpage even by zooming out?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a colored border around my webpage. I want the border to be "stuck on the edges" even if the page is scrolled or zoomed out. Snipped screenshot below shows the appearance of the border when zoomed out. Currently, here's my code.

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 5px solid #d7000f;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RbSs.png)

Comment: By 'stuck on the edges' do you mean that it will form a border just inside the viewport rather than round the whole body? And that it will remain there even as the user zooms in or out?

Comment: yes. on the viewpoint of the user. I actually did it once but when I zoom out, the border also goes with the body that was zoomed out and shows the border as a box halfway on the screen instead.

Comment: The question flagged as a duplicate was looking for a border around the body. This question is asking about a border around the viewport. Changing the pseudo element to position fixed fixes it to the viewport but you need some JS to account for any scrollbars.  It also increases the border size on zoom which may or may not be what is required.

Comment: does the duplcate question answer your question? I feel it doesn't but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pseudo-element` to body:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
body::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}
```